# Why is this JOIN+AND query identical to this JOIN query?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an SQLite database with an events, a participants tables, and a third table linking each participant to each event they attended.  I wanted a list of the events that a given participant attended.

```
only_joined_table = mydb.execute('SELECT * FROM event_participant_link LEFT JOIN event '
                                 'ON event_participant_link.event_id = event.event_id').fetchall()

joined_table = mydb.execute('SELECT * FROM event_participant_link LEFT JOIN event '
                            'ON event_participant_link.event_id = event.event_id '
                            'AND event_participant_link.participant_id = ?',
                            [participant_id]).fetchall()

print(len(only_joined_table), len(joined_table)) # Result: 7929 7929
```

These two queries apparently show the same number of entries, indicating that `AND event_participant_link.participant_id = participant_id` doesn't actually do anything.  Is this not the right way to add a constraining filter on a joined table? Or does something else pop up that explains the unexpected result?

Comment: Take some time to read about [LEFT join](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-left-join/).

Comment: @forpas Oh, I HAD read about the kinds of joins.  I just completely misunderstood.  INNER JOIN is what I needed, and seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEFT JOIN, is "bound" to give you all the rows in `event_participant_link`- I won't be surprised if 7929 just happens to be the count(*) of table `event_participant_link`.
What you're trying to achieve, might just be obtained by query-

`` select distinct(event_id) from event_participant_link where participant_id = ?`,[participant_id] ``

Comment: Yeeeah, I misunderstood LEFT JOIN.  I see that what I needed to do was INNER JOIN.  That query won't give me the right result as I'm basically looking for the event table (which contains other things like event date) and not the event_ids linking to it.  But `SELECT * FROM epl INNER JOIN event ON epl.event_id = event.event_id AND epl.participant_id = ?` does work.

Comment: great! you may accept this answer if this served the purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

This will ensure that the query only returns the events attended by the participant with the specified ID

```
joined_table = mydb.execute('''
SELECT * FROM event_participant_link LEFT JOIN event 
ON event_participant_link.event_id = event.event_id 
WHERE event_participant_link.participant_id = {}'''.format(participant_id)).fetchall()
```